# Inserir dados em tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tenho um formulário com action para essa script e método POST, e alguns valores precisam ser inseridos em tabelas diferentes do banco de dados, mas ou só insere em uma tabela, ou não insere em nenhuma.

```
<?php

if($_POST["acao"] == "inserir"){
        inserirCliente();
}

function inserirCliente(){
    $bd = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "projeto_ap2" );
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente(cpf, nome, dt_nasc) "
                . "VALUES ('{$_POST["cpfCliente"]}','{$_POST["nomeCliente"]}','{$_POST["dataNascimentoCliente"]}')";

            "INSERT INTO cliente_endereco(cpf_cliente, cep, cidade, estado, bairro, logradouro, numero)"
                . "VALUES ('{$_POST["cpfCliente"]}','{$_POST["cepCliente"]}','{$_POST["cidadeCliente"]}','{$_POST["estadoCliente"]}','{$_POST["bairroCliente"]}','{$_POST["logradouroCliente"]}','{$_POST["numeroCasaCliente"]}')";

            "INSERT INTO cliente_telefone(cpf_cliente, telefone_cliente)"
                . "VALUES ('{$_POST["cpfCliente"]}','{$_POST["telefoneCliente"]}')";

    $bd->query($sql);
    $bd->close();
}

header("Location: index.php");
```

Comment: já tentou separar as três queries em três variáveis e depois executá-las?

Answer (score 2):

Se eu bem me lembro, só tem como executar uma query de cada vez no `mysqli` mesmo, mas qual o problema em executar uma de cada vez?

```
$sql1 = "INSERT INTO cliente(cpf, nome, dt_nasc) "
            . "VALUES ('{$_POST["cpfCliente"]}','{$_POST["nomeCliente"]}','{$_POST["dataNascimentoCliente"]}')";

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO cliente_endereco(cpf_cliente, cep, cidade, estado, bairro, logradouro, numero)"
            . "VALUES ('{$_POST["cpfCliente"]}','{$_POST["cepCliente"]}','{$_POST["cidadeCliente"]}','{$_POST["estadoCliente"]}','{$_POST["bairroCliente"]}','{$_POST["logradouroCliente"]}','{$_POST["numeroCasaCliente"]}')";

$sql3 = "INSERT INTO cliente_telefone(cpf_cliente, telefone_cliente)"
            . "VALUES ('{$_POST["cpfCliente"]}','{$_POST["telefoneCliente"]}')";

$bd->query($sql1);
$bd->query($sql2);
$bd->query($sql3);
$bd->close();
```

Comment: O sql3 não foi salvo, mas os dados POST estão corretos

Comment: @Lucas, verificou se a tabela `cliente_telefone` ou colunas `cpf_cliente` e `telefone_cliente` estão com esse mesmo nome no banco de dados?

Comment: Sim, estão com o mesmo nome. Tá tudo certinho, só não entendo pq não inseriu

Comment: @Lucas, ambos CPF e Telefone estão definidos como tipo `VARCHAR` ou alguma variação de string? Deve ter algo errado, ou na query, ou no banco de dados.

Comment: Deu certo aqui. CPF e Telefone estavam definidos como int, mas o número tecnicamente é grande dms pra inteiro. Alterei pra BIGINT e funcionou. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: @Lucas, CPF pode começar com o número 0, se você defini-lo como um tipo numérico você irá perder os zeros a esquerda.